# MediaRecorder Web API not working while recording webrtc stream coming from IOS in Mac-Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

i am using MediaRecorder Web API to record webrtc stream which is coming from native IOS appication. 
1. MediaRecorder not working in MAC-chrome browser specifically while recording webrtc stream coming from ios native application(working on windows chrome)
2. i am able to display webrtc stream coming from ios in the UI but not able to record the same stream 
3. i have noticed ondataavailable method not invoking after starting  recording the stream.

i have used this link https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/ for recording webrtc stream in my application

NOTE: This issue occurring only after updating webrtc framework in native IOS application and MediaRecorder Working as expected in mac-chrome if we use old webrtc framework in native IOS application.

can anyone help me why specifically ondataavailable method not invoking in MAC-chrome

i am not able to figure out this is MediaRecorder issue in mac-chrome or latest frame work issue in native IOS application?

```
window.WebRTC.startRecording = function(localStream, remoteStream) {
var options = {
    mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'
};

if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
    console.log(options.mimeType + ' is not Supported');
    options = {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'
    };
    if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
        console.log(options.mimeType + ' is not Supported');
        options = {
            mimeType: 'video/webm'
        };
        if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(options.mimeType)) {
            console.log(options.mimeType + ' is not Supported');
            options = {`enter code here`
                mimeType: ''
            };
        }
    }
}
try {
//   debugger;
    window.WebRTC.recording.mediaRecorderLocal = new MediaRecorder(localStream, options);
    window.WebRTC.recording.mediaRecorderRemote = new MediaRecorder(remoteStream, options);
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ' + e);
    alert('Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ' +
        e + '. mimeType: ' + options.mimeType);
    return;
}

window.WebRTC.recording.mediaRecorderRemote.start(1000);

window.WebRTC.recording.mediaRecorderRemote.ondataavailable = function(event) {
if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
  window.WebRTC.recording.recordedBlobsRemote.push(event.data);
}
},
```

Comment: our IOS developers fixed this using codecs- VP8 instead of codecs-H264 at the application layer.

Comment: Any chance this bug is only present since Chrome 73? Because since Chrome 73, Chrome does not record all webrtc streams on Mac, Windows/Linux does.